# can I NSLog a JSON and see its real format?

Tags: ios, json, nslog

I was just wondering about this `NSLog` vs JSON issue i've had for a while.

So I have my `responseObject` (type is `id`), can I simply `NSLog` it ?

When i do, i see a JSON-like text, but there are some massive issues, and I don't know if its the real JSON that's a problem or the `NSLog` that fails.

Can I trust the `NSLog` about this? Or if I want to print it "the web way", do I need to do something else?

Comment: Generally, JSON is received as an NSData object.  To NSLog it (in any meaningful form) you need to first convert to NSString (initWithData:encoding:).  Or you can convert to dictionaries/arrays with NSJSONSerialization and log that -- it's not *exactly* an JSON representation, but very close.

Comment: (If the "massive issues" you're talking about are having `()` where there should be `[]`, `=` where there should be `:`, `;` where there should be `,`, and some missing quote symbols, then you're dumping the NSArray/NSDictionary representation and that's "normal".)

Comment: Alright thanks !
Yeah it was pretty much that that was troubling me. But because i had errors with that data later in the code, i was trying to source it and wanted to know if my error was pre or post json.
Now i know the JSON is fine :)

Comment: (The dump format for NSArray and NSDictionary essentially predates JSON, and it's basically just dumb luck that the dump format resembles the corresponding JSON as much as it does.)

Answer (score 5):

Once you've got the `NSData` object containing the HTTP response content, perhaps using:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:someURL];
```

you normally "parse" it into Objective-C objects using:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                     options:kNilOptions 
                                                       error:&error];
```

However you can also log the data response by first turning it into a string:

```
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                             encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Response JSON=%@", jsonString);
```

Answer (score 1):

If your responseObject is type id and if you try to print them with NSLog than it just return the object name.

To get the more detail about the JSON follow the below URL:
[How to output JSon data in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11396455/how-to-output-json-data-in-objective-c)

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Do as below for well formatted log of response.

```
id jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
NSLog(@"Response : %@",[jsonResponse description]);
```

Hope, This will work.